# How to generate rows to insert in between existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

At our company clients are assessed at a regular basis at which they are graded. The result of the assessment gets stored in the database (SQL Server 2017) and the result would look like this.

```
ClientID  AssessID AssessMonth RepMonth AssessGrade
1     100      01/2018     01/2018  0.98
1     149      07/2018     07/2018  0.80
1     199      01/2019     01/2019  0.45
```

So far, so good. Now from the regulators office we have goten the request to provide them with the Assessment Grades for each Client for each Reporting Month. This means that somehow we need to repeat the first record for each subsequent ReportingMonth until a new Assessment is done (or keep repeating it if there is no new assessment). Making the result to look like this:

```
ClientID AssessID AssessMonth   RepMonth AssessResult
1    100      01/2018   01/2018  0.98
1    100      01/2018   02/2018  0.98
1    100      01/2018   03/2018  0.98
1    100      01/2018   04/2018  0.98
1    100      01/2018   05/2018  0.98
1    100      01/2018   06/2018  0.98
1    149      07/2018   07/2018  0.80
1    149      07/2018   08/2018  0.80
1    149      07/2018   09/2018  0.80
1    149      07/2018   10/2018  0.80
1    149      07/2018   11/2018  0.80
1    149      07/2018   12/2018  0.80
1    199      01/2019   01/2019  0.45
```

As you may see each record is repeated until there is a new assessment for that client. Only the RepMonth gets a new value which is one higher than its predecessor. The records that are now in between do not exist in the database.

I can generate a table that holds all possible Reporting Months but I have no clue on how to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL standard defines SQL tables to be stored **orderless** and resultsets which are fetched without ORDER BY are also **orderless**, so what you are planning for inserting does not really make sense and does not help..

Comment: What you want is using a calendar table to generate the "missing" records when selecting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines would work (I've used test data and parameterized with a start and end month):

```
DECLARE
    @StartMonth date = '2019-01-01'
    , @EndMonth date = '2019-04-01'

DECLARE @t table
(
    ClientID int
    , AssessID int
    , AssessMonth date
    , RepMonth date
    , AssessGrade decimal(19, 2)
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (1, 1, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', 0.5)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (1, 2, '2019-04-01', '2019-04-01', 0.9)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (2, 1, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', 0.4)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (2, 2, '2019-03-01', '2019-03-01', 0.3)
;

WITH cteMonths
AS
(
    SELECT CAST(@EndMonth AS date) RepMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, RepMonth)
    FROM cteMonths
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, -1, RepMonth) >= @StartMonth
)
,

cteMonthsClients
AS
(
    SELECT
        M.RepMonth
        , C.ClientID
    FROM
        cteMonths M 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM @t) C
)

SELECT
    M.ClientID
    , M.RepMonth
    , ISNULL(T.AssessID, T2.AssessID) AssessID
    , ISNULL(T.AssessMonth, T2.AssessMonth) AssessMonth
    , ISNULL(T.AssessGrade, T2.AssessGrade) AssessGrade
FROM
    cteMonthsClients M
    LEFT JOIN @t T ON
        M.RepMonth = T.RepMonth
        AND M.ClientID = T.ClientID
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            AssessID
            , AssessMonth
            , AssessGrade
        FROM @t T2
        WHERE
            T2.ClientID = M.ClientID
            AND T2.RepMonth < M.RepMonth
        ORDER BY RepMonth DESC
    ) T2
ORDER BY
    ClientID
    , RepMonth
```

Comment: We tested both sugested solutions and found this one the most suitable. We did however used the EOMONTH function while declaring the EndDate to make it more flexible. When you do that you also must use it in the cteMonths like this. WITH cteMonths
AS
(
    SELECT CAST(EndMonth AS date) RepMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EOMONTH (DATEADD(MONTH, -1, RepMonth))
    FROM cteMonths
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, -1, RepMonth) >= StartMonth
)

Comment: Yes, using `EOMONTH()` where necessary is very important - I had assumed a month start date in my answer, so it wouldn't be required in that case, but it is something that's very easy to overlook when using CTEs like this. (Please mark the answer as correct if the solution is working.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach, in which you will have to use a date dimension table, which will give you the following output:

```
ClientID    AssessID    AssessMonth RepMonth    AssessGrade
1           100         01/2018     01/2018     0.98
1           100         01/2018     02/2018     0.98
1           100         01/2018     03/2018     0.98
1           100         01/2018     04/2018     0.98
1           100         01/2018     05/2018     0.98
1           100         01/2018     06/2018     0.98
1           149         07/2018     07/2018     0.80
1           149         07/2018     08/2018     0.80
1           149         07/2018     09/2018     0.80
1           149         07/2018     10/2018     0.80
1           149         07/2018     11/2018     0.80
1           149         07/2018     12/2018     0.80
1           199         01/2019     01/2019     0.45
```

With Following:

```
--Create Assessment Table 
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE 
(
    ClientID INT,
    AssessID INT,
    AssessMonth VARCHAR(MAX),
    RepMonth VARCHAR(MAX),
    AssessGrade NUMERIC(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES 
(1,100,'01/2018','01/2018',0.98),
(1,149,'07/2018','07/2018',0.80),
(1,199,'01/2019','01/2019',0.45)

--Dummy date dimension table 
DECLARE @MonthYear AS TABLE 
(
    [Month] VARCHAR(10), 
    [Year] VARCHAR(10), 
    [MonthYear] AS [Month] +'/'+ [Year]
)

INSERT INTO @MonthYear VALUES 
('01',2017),('02',2017),('03',2017),('04',2017),('05',2017),('06',2017),('07',2017),('08',2017),('09',2017),('10',2017),('11',2017),('12',2017),
('01',2018),('02',2018),('03',2018),('04',2018),('05',2018),('06',2018),('07',2018),('08',2018),('09',2018),('10',2018),('11',2018),('12',2018),
('01',2019),('02',2019),('03',2019),('04',2019),('05',2019),('06',2019),('07',2019),('08',2019),('09',2019),('10',2019),('11',2019),('12',2019),
('01',2020),('02',2020),('03',2020),('04',2020),('05',2020)

--Final select statement 
SELECT 
    t.ClientID,
    t.AssessID, 
    t.AssessMonth,
    m.MonthYear AS RepMonth, 
    t.AssessGrade
FROM 
    @Table1 t
CROSS JOIN @MonthYear m
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        AssessMonth
    FROM 
        @Table1 
    WHERE 
        AssessID > t.AssessID
    ORDER BY AssessID
) o 
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        AssessMonth 
    FROM
        @Table1
    ORDER BY 
        AssessID DESC
) o2
WHERE 
    (CAST(RIGHT('0' + RIGHT(m.MonthYear, 4) + LEFT(m.MonthYear, 2), 6) AS INT) < CAST(RIGHT('0' + RIGHT(o.AssessMonth, 4) + LEFT(o.AssessMonth, 2), 6) AS INT) 
     OR (O2.AssessMonth = t.AssessMonth AND CAST(RIGHT('0' + RIGHT(m.MonthYear, 4) + LEFT(m.MonthYear, 2), 6) AS INT) <= CAST(RIGHT('0' + RIGHT(o2.AssessMonth, 4) + LEFT(o2.AssessMonth, 2), 6) AS INT)))
    AND CAST(RIGHT('0' + RIGHT(m.MonthYear, 4) + LEFT(m.MonthYear, 2), 6) AS INT) >= CAST(RIGHT('0' + RIGHT(t.AssessMonth, 4) + LEFT(t.AssessMonth, 2), 6) AS INT)
ORDER BY 
    t.ClientID, t.AssessID, M.Year, M.Month
```