# Create rows between values of column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following customer sku level dataset

```
Customer customer_name  customer_category sku sku_name week   revenue
       1 abc            dsas              221 test     201701     100
       1 abc            dsas              221 test     201704      90
       1 abc            dsas              222 new      201701     100
```

I need to create rows based on max and min value of week above.

The customer and sku attributes (customer_name, customer_category, sku, sku_name) should be re-populated for the new rows, but the revenue for the new rows should be 0.

The data is at customer-sku-week level.

Output would look like:

```
Customer customer_name customer_category sku sku_name week   revenue
       1 abc           dsas              221 test     201701 100*total 4 rows 
       1 abc           dsas              221 test     201702   0    
       1 abc           dsas              221 test     201703   0
       1 abc           dsas              221 test     201704  90    
       1 abc           dsas              222 new      201701 100*total 1 row
```

I was trying to do a right join the above table against a dummy table with all week values possible.

I would like to know how I will be able to repopulate customer and sku attributes for new rows and still keep revenue as 0

Comment: That said, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the point of this code would be to find and insert missing weeks for each sku, which were not initially inserted due to not having any revenue?

Comment: i think the main problem/point  is a more a review display by generating records on runtime on a select.. @TygerTy As SQL tables are **orderless** by ANSI/ISO standards inserting new record(s) between is a bad idea as you assuming then MySQL stores the tables data in a order...

Comment: I was actually thinking that, myself, as if you insert a new table row, it isn't like excel which bumps everything down.  It will insert it at the bottom of the table with the next possible `id`, if you have an auto-incremented field. In your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075187/how-to-generate-rows-to-insert-in-between-existing-rows) you mention this, I believe.  So you'd need some other way to organize the data, probably by making sure to order by the week value. Which may require a very complex query, or to just do several queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark SQL using the DataFrame API, this could be done using these steps:

1. Using a window function `lead` get the next week
2. Using `sequence` function create an array of missing weeks
3. Explode the array using `explode_outer`
4. Using another window function `row_number` together with `when` condition set the revenue col to 0 for the missing weeks.

Assuming the data is only within one year (otherwise the sequence has to be adjusted), the query can look like this (in PySpark):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead, row_number, col, sequence, expr,  explode_outer, coalesce, when
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('customer', 'sku').orderBy('week')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('customer', 'sku', 'week').orderBy('week_2')

result = (
  df
  .withColumn('next_week', lead('week').over(w))
  .withColumn('missed', expr("sequence(week, next_week-1, 1)"))
  .withColumn('week_2', explode_outer('missed'))
  .withColumn('week_3', coalesce('week_2', 'week'))
  .withColumn('r', row_number().over(w2))
  .withColumn('revenue_2', when(~(col('r') == 1), 0).otherwise(col('revenue')))
  .select(
    'customer', 'customer_name', 'customer_category', 'sku', 'sku_name',
    col('week_3').alias('week'),
    col('revenue_2').alias('revenue')
  )
)

result.show()
+--------+-------------+-----------------+---+--------+------+-------+
|customer|customer_name|customer_category|sku|sku_name|week  |revenue|
+--------+-------------+-----------------+---+--------+------+-------+
|1       |abc          |dsas             |221|test    |201701|100    |
|1       |abc          |dsas             |221|test    |201702|0      |
|1       |abc          |dsas             |221|test    |201703|0      |
|1       |abc          |dsas             |221|test    |201704|90     |
|1       |abc          |dsas             |222|new     |201701|100    |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+---+--------+------+-------+
```

I hope this is what you need.